# linked-list root node loses its data when using printf() in main

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm creating my first linked list and I have found something weird, in my main function whenever I call `printf()` the start pointer which points to the first node in my linked list shows that the data is garbage and the next pointer is a very random address, unlike if I didn't use `printf()` it seems good and all nodes are created and all good!

```
#include <iostream>

int node_counter = 0;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

node* start;

void creat_ll()
{
    node n1;
    start = &n1;
    n1.data = 0;
    n1.next = NULL;
    node_counter++;
}

void insertNode(int x)
{
    node* ptr = start;

    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr ->next;
    }

    node* temp = ptr;
    ptr = new(node);
    ptr->data = x;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    printf("node number: %d\n",x);
    temp->next = ptr;
    node_counter++;
}

int main()
{
    creat_ll();
    insertNode(10);
    insertNode(20);
    // printf("number of nodes = %d \n", node_counter);
    insertNode(30);
    printf("test\n");
    printf("number of nodes = %d \n", node_counter);
    insertNode(40);
    insertNode(50);
    insertNode(60);
    insertNode(70);
    printf("number of nodes = %d \n", node_counter);
}
```

Comment: `start = & n1;` - and you just turned `start` into a dangling pointer, as `n1` is local to the function. Why did you assume you didn't need to use dynamic allocation in `creat_ll` when you do in `insertNode`?

Comment: You should compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -g -fsanitize=address,undefined` if you are using `g++` or `clang++`. Your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: the tag says 'c++' but this is very much not c++. If you intend it to be c++ then have a class list and another class node, and use smart pointers

Comment: @pm100 Please don't just blame him. You could provide reference material on how to implement a proper linked-list class using the things that you have mentioned. Or maybe write your own answer.

Comment: Tactical note: A global variable tracking the root of the linked list ensures you can never have more than one linked list and adds to the complexity of debugging because `start` can be accessed and changed anywhere in the code. Don't do this to yourself. Make a class that manages the linked list or pass around a local variable by reference.

Comment: Smart pointers aren't even essential. Just need to write a destructor that cleans up appropriately.

Comment: Not a big fan of smart pointers in linked lists. They transform destruction that could be iterative into a potentially stack-killing recursion. You need to have bounds on the size of the list to survive.

Comment: I would like to thank you all for your contribution, efforts, and time. also, I would like to clarify that I am doing this for pure learning purposes, not for any commercial-related stuff. just to get deeper knowledge and understanding of the linked lists, @UnholySheep that's the point I wanted to try random stuff also I know that the next pointer in node will be destroyed when I am out of scope but I want to clarify that the code still working only start to do random stuff when printf() gets executed if you tried to comment/uncomment the print() in the main you will notice it

Comment: *"code still working"* - your code has *undefined behavior*. Appearing to work fine is one possible symptom of UB, just as randomly stopping to work again due to unrelated changes

Comment: yeah i got it, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people mentioned in the comments, the problem is not related to `printf()`, but to dangling pointers. In the local scope of `creat_ll()`, you've created a variable `node n1` (allocated on the stack) and then assigned the address of `n1` to `start`, which has global scope. Once the `creat_ll()` function exits, everything in the scope of `creat_ll()` is gone, including `n1`. So in `main()`, `start` points to deleted data.

This, of course, would be solved if you allocate all your variables on the heap (i.e. use keywords `new` and `delete`). On the heap, you can create or delete variables from anywhere and they'll stick around until you delete them (or until your program exits). If you allocate `n1` on the heap, the memory survives even after `create_ll()` exits. However, with this, you take on the responsibility of managing the underlying memory yourself, meaning that once you're done with your list, something has to go back and delete all the nodes; otherwise, the nodes stick around and you end up with a memory leak.

*Cherno* has a great video on object lifetime that you can find here: https://youtu.be/iNuTwvD6ciI. At 4:30, he shows an example that is nearly identical to yours.

So a better overall implementation is to create a `class` that handles all of this. We should be able to create a linked list, add nodes to it (allocate memory), remove nodes from it (delete memory), and, once we're done with it, delete all memory associated with the linked list.

Below is an example implementation. I'll leave the implementation of the `remove()` method to you.

```
#include <cstdio>


struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList() = default;

    // Add x to the end of the list.
    void push_back(const int value)
    {
        if (root == nullptr)
        {
            root = new node{ };
            root->data = value;
            root->next = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            node* ptr { root };

            while (ptr->next != nullptr)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }

            node* const newNode { new node{ } };
            newNode->data = value;
            newNode->next = nullptr;
            ptr->next = newNode;
        }

        ++size;
    }

    // Remove the first occurrence of x.
    void remove(const int value)
    {
        // left as an exercise
    }

    void printList() const
    {
        std::printf("Number of nodes: %lu\n", size);

        const node* ptr { root };

        while (ptr != nullptr)
        {
            std::printf("%d ", ptr->data);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }

        std::printf("\n");
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        const node* ptr { root };

        while (ptr != nullptr)
        {
            const node* const next { ptr->next };
            delete ptr;
            ptr = next;
        }

        size = 0;
    }

private:
    node* root { nullptr };
    std::size_t size { 0 };
};


int main()
{
    LinkedList ll { LinkedList{ } };

    ll.push_back(10);
    ll.push_back(20);
    ll.printList();
    ll.push_back(30);
    ll.push_back(40);
    ll.printList();
}
```

*Output:*

```
Number of nodes: 2
10 20 
Number of nodes: 4
10 20 30 40
```

---

**EDIT:** Here is a minimal example of memory getting overridden due to the stack getting popped. Note that this behavior is undefined, so depending on the compiler you're using, you may see some output or get a segfault. I'm using gcc and I get the output shown below.

```
#include <iostream>                                                                             
#include <string>                                                                               
                                                                                                
std::string* s;                                                                                 
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
void createString()                                                                             
{                                                                                               
    std::string local_string = "This string is about to get popped out of the stack.";          
    s = &local_string;                                                                          
    std::cout << *s << std::endl;                                                               
}                                                                                               
                                                                                                
int main()                                                                                      
{                                                                                               
    createString();                                                                             
    std::cout << *s << std::endl;                                                               
                                                                                                
    return 0;                                                                                   
}
```

*Output 1*

```
This string is about to get popped out of the stack.
0D8Vbout to get popped out of the stack.
```

*Output 2*

```
This string is about to get popped out of the stack.
Ubout to get popped out of the stack.
```

*Output 3*

```
This string is about to get popped out of the stack.
tUbout to get popped out of the stack.
```

Comment: Thank you for your time answering this, indeed the problem is with the dangling pointer when I just modified the creat_ll() to be dynamic allocation it solved all the issue, but could you just illustrate why this was happening ? i mean the code was executing fine and creating the nodes till you interrupt it with print()

Comment: I edited my answer and included a minimal illustration. Hope that helps. 

It was happening because `n1` was going out of scope, so you were losing ownership of the memory held by `n1`. Your code isn't illegal; it's just undefined. The code may behave differently if compiled with another compiler or run on a different machine (e.g. I was getting a segfault and couldn't run your code). If, on your machine, you get a segfault only after hitting `printf()`, it just means your program accidentally managed to stay within the memory it owns until something in `printf()` threw it out of bounds.

Comment: This makes much more sense and very logical, thank you so much